# Yii::app()->user->setFlash Access Denied in a controller

Tags: php, yii

I am trying this in a controller:

```
Yii::app()->user->setFlash('success', "message to user.");
```

but I get this error:

```
[exception.CHttpException.403] exception 'CHttpException' with message 
'You do not have access to do this action.'
in /yii/framework/web/auth/CAccessControlFilter.php:182
Stack trace:
 /yii/framework/web/auth/CAccessControlFilter.php(145):
   CAccessControlFilter->accessDenied(Object(WebUser)

 /home/iteb/yii/framework/web/filters/CFilter.php(38): 
   CAccessControlFilter->preFilter(Object(CFilterChain))
 ...
```

Controller code:

```
<?php
class UserReportController extends Controller {
public function filters() {
    return array(
        'accessControl', 
    );
}

public function accessRules() {
    return array(
        array('allow', 
            'actions' => array('create'),
            'users' => array('*'),
        ),
    );
}

public function actionCreate() {
    $model = new UserReport;
    if (isset($_POST['UserReport'])) {
         $model->attributes = $_POST['UserReport'];
         if ($model->save()) {
                Yii::app()->user->setFlash('success', "saved!");

        }
    }

}

}
```

I don't know what to do.

Comment: Can you post complete code of your controller?

Comment: Have you checked it with after removing accessRules() function. If it had worked we should remove that block since it's not necessary if you want to give access for all users...

Comment: Add a render of redirect to your action please, and come report back.